# How do I know what to send to the Serial Port?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I do know how to Open, Read, Write and Close a serial port using MFC/C++. The problem is I do not know what to send to the serial port.

I have seen my colleagues sending something like `21 04 07 00 08 00 0F 22`. 
I converted it to control and it says ! EOT BEL NUL BS NUL SI "

Which also means ! (end of text)(bell)(null)(backspace)(null)(shift in)"

I'm not sure if what I have translated would be useful but I'm trying to understand what my have colleague sent and perhaps I could devise my own lines of hexadecimal to send to the port.
I am relatively new to this. Should I be unclear in my question or I am asking the question in a wrong way, please enlighten me. I am ready to learn and I am not asking for direct answers.

I hope my fellow programming seniors in Stack Overflow can help me out here.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen my colleagues sending something like 21 04 07 00 08 00 0F
>   22.

Serial Port communication is just a way of data transfer mechanism between two systems/applications. You can send data back and forth. In your case, the above message is transferred into array of bytes, when you read this from the other side of the COM port. You will get something like:

```
myrecievedarray[0] = 21;

myrecievedarray[1] = 04;

...
myrecievedarray[6] = 0F;
```

Now, it is your turn/ or up to the listener on the other side to interpret this hexa values and what it means. This could be commands to turn on a motor or a machine etc... 
And by the way, usually in this kinda data transfer you send a fixed byte such as (`7E`) in the beginning  to tell you the beginning of a data package and same for a footer at the end to indicate the end of the data package.

Comment: Hi Sammer. Thanks for the explanation. However, the problem that I am facing is to try and interpret what this byte is trying to say on the other side of the serial port so I can edit it and make a better one. Or is there any useful links that I can study more on this so I can develop or improve the byte on my own? Thanks for the advice on (7E) too, I will keep that in mind.